# How does Javascript/jQuery cache actually facilitate the modification of DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dom, optimization

you may say I am a middle level javascript/jQuery developer. I am a basic knowledge on computer science, programming, data structure and algorithm etc. And I will usually read online to learn how to write better and faster javascript/jQuery code.

In the internet, I have always taught to use cache/ variable to store DOM first (by Javascript/jQuery). When you in the program want to get them or use them again, you can get it from cache, no need to get access to the DOM again. However, I find 2 things confusing to me that are stated below.

1. modify DOM using cache/variable

```
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $p = $("p");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text1</b>.");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text2</b>.");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text3</b>.");
  });
```

As I understand, when cache `$("p")` into `$p`, theoretically, you make any change to `$p` will only modify the `$p` but not the original DOM. However, the true is that the change will apply to `$("p")` also, and further realize on the DOM, HTML, browser and being rendering out to user. It is fine then I will assume `$p` in this case, is cached as an object and contains method to modify the DOM. However, if it is the case, there comes a problem. The problem is when you `.append()` something to `$p` and `$p` will access the DOM every time, in this case using cache `$p.append(" <b>Appended text1</b>.");` or no cache `$("p").append(" <b>Appended text1</b>.");` will make no difference?

2. cache value will change along with DOM content change

```
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $p = $("p"); 
    $p_dummy = $("p");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text1</b>.");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text2</b>.");
    $p.append(" <b>Appended text3</b>.");
    console.log($p_dummy.html());
  });
```

Continue on the above example. this time I cache an object `$("p")` into another variable `$p_dummy`, and then modify the `$("p")` and console.log the content of `$p_dummy` out. Again, theoretically, I cache it before modifying the `$("p")`, however, `console.log($p_dummy.html())` would show the latest updated content of `$("p")` but not the content at the time I am storing it. In this case, I made two assumptions. First assumption, any DOM change will update any variable made on it. That means you cache 10 variables on `$("p")`, the 10 variables will change along with. The more variables you made, the slower your coding may be. Second assumption, the variable actually makes no change. It is that when using `.html()`, this method will get access to the DOM again and get back the current content to you. If it is the case, my question is, you have to access to the DOM even you are using a variable, why don't we directly use `$("p")` all the time and ignore using variable?

These questions confuse me a long time. I have tried to search and work out answer in this period by myself, but still cannot make it. Hoped anyone can help or discuss about them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The only thing that `var $p = $("p")` "caches" is the lookup, so you don't have to perform it over and over.  It doesn't have anything to do with disconnecting the element found from the DOM

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also found that for the code`var myLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); alert(myLi.length); document.getElementsByTagName("li")[1].remove(); alert(myLi.length);` when I delete an element from DOM, the lookup cache will also notice the change. Does this mean that more cache make more update and will result in slower DOM change?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName  This method returns a *live* collection.  Not everything does that.  Also that is a native method, not a jQuery method, and the assumption should not be made that they will behave the same.

Comment: I think it talks about htmlcollection, but my questions are, 1.why cache for htmlcollection would be faster 2. will the cache be automatic updated once the htmlcollection change?

Comment: #1) It is faster for the same reason why `var x = 3 + 4;` and using `x` going forward in your code would be faster than repeating the same operation over and over.  Because you are doing the work once, saving the result, and reusing the result.  In the case of jQuery, not only is there the work needed to find the element(s) in the DOM, but there is over head with creating the jQuery objects.  Reusing the lookup results cuts out the repeated operation and repeated over head.  #2) No.